# How to query datas of Ara where location is "Budapest"?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<OnlineRadios>
  <Area Location="Budapest">
    <Radio>
      <Name>
        NeoFM
      </Name>
      <Előadó>
        Balage
      </Előadó>
    </Radio>
    <Radio>
      <Name>
        NeoFM
      </Name>
      <Előadó>
        Balage
      </Előadó>
    </Radio>
    <Radio>
      <Name>
        NeoFM
      </Name>
      <Előadó>
        Balage
      </Előadó>
    </Radio>
  </Area>
  <Area Location="Kecskemét">
    <Radio>
      <Name>
        NeoFM
      </Name>
      <Előadó>
        Balage
      </Előadó>
    </Radio>
    <Radio>
      <Name>
        NeoFM
      </Name>
      <Előadó>
        Balage
      </Előadó>
    </Radio>
    <Radio>
      <Name>
        NeoFM
      </Name>
      <Előadó>
        Balage
      </Előadó>
    </Radio>
  </Area>
</OnlineRadios>
```

I want to query all radiostation where the location same with find location. So I gave a condition, then I would have to fill the result.
I tried

```
var x = (from a in XmlFile2.Elements("Area")
          where a.Attribute("Location").Value == "Budapest"
          select a;
```

but It doesn't work.
Or not enough. If you know pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

`Elements()` only gets the *direct* children of the current node (as opposed to `Descendants()`), you want to qualify with the root node in this case - this works :

```
var x =   from a in XmlFile2.Root.Elements("Area")
          where a.Attribute("Location").Value == "Budapest"
          select a;
```